# How to encourage growth from seed in an avocado tree?

Tags: pruning, avocado

I have an avocado seedling. I've recently pruned the tree and there is new growth visible.
However, when I inspect the seed, I see multiple sprouts just waiting there. How do I encourage those to grow from the seed?

Pruned tree and new growth:

[image: new growth]

Seed:

[image: seed]

The full plant looks as follows:

[image]